# SQL Count total given a Where/Having parameter

Tags: sql, count

Ive got the follow sql which counts how many actors have more than 1 role based on actorID

```
SELECT COUNT (actorID) 
from ROLE
GROUP BY actorID
HAVING COUNT (actorID) > 3;
```

It gives me the followin result which is correct

```
COUNT(ACTORID)
         4
         5
         4
         4
```

However I WANT it to give me the total of 4 (4 actors have more than 3 film roles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this in two steps.

First, identify the actors with more than 3 films, as you have done.  Then count those records in a separate query...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT   actorID
  FROM     ROLE
  GROUP BY actorID
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 3
)
  AS actors
```

Comment: Thanks! It didnt like the As Actors at the end but other worked! perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting HAVING for WHERE

Comment: @LillyPop - If you correct your answer, people will remove their -1's.  But as it stands your answer suggests trying something syntactically impossible.  Because it's a completely incorrect answer, it gets -1 to signify that.  But if you alter your answer to be something at least valid, then you don't get -1.